# GoToWebinar - Request not in expected format - RestSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, api, restsharp

Similar to this forum post:
https://developer.citrixonline.com/forum/request-not-expected-format

However he didn't really explain what he found was wrong with his code.

I'm using RestSharp to make API calls. I've been able to get it to work great to pull an list of upcoming webinars however when I try to register participant I keep getting a 400/Request not in expected format error.

Following this documentation https://developer.citrixonline.com/api/gotowebinar-rest-api/apimethod/create-registrant, here is my code:

```
var client = new RestClient(string.Format("https://api.citrixonline.com/G2W/rest/organizers/{0}/webinars/{1}/registrants", "300000000000xxxxxx", btn.CommandArgument));
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/vnd.citrix.g2wapi-v1.1+json");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "OAuth oauth_token=" + System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoToWebinar"]);

request.AddParameter("firstName", LoggedInUser.FirstName);
request.AddParameter("lastName", LoggedInUser.LastName);
request.AddParameter("email", LoggedInUser.Email);

var response = client.Execute(request);
var statusCode = response.StatusCode;
```

Any insights on how I can figure out why I keep getting that error?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using AddParamter (which adds key/value parameters to the request body), you need to write JSON instead:

```
request.DataFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddBody(new {
    firstName = LoggedInUser.FirstName,
    lastName = LoggedInUser.LastName,
    email = LoggedInUser.Email
});
```

You'll also need to clear the handlers (which automatically set the Accept header) if you want to specify them directly:

```
client.ClearHandlers();
```

Comment: That did it, thank you so much! I thought there was an option to either use the AddBody OR AddParameter and if it was set to DataFormat = Json it would produce the Json body from the Parameters.